# How to postpone a key nmap to its default mapping in vim

Tags: vim

How to yank a **method** inside a .cpp, then when **pasting** in a .h file, remove the `MyFooClass::` from the yanked text.

Example:

```
file.cpp:

bool MyFooClass::myFooPrivateMethod()
```

When pasting in file.h, I want:

```
file.h

class MyFooClass{
...
   bool myFooPrivateMethod();
...
```

How to `nmap p` to remove `::MyFooClass` and change `{` from to `;` in cpp.

The thing is. I need to change the paste behavior depending of the destination. How to treat the yanked text and postpone for the default `p paste`

1. Find out destination file
2. nmap p to a function where `MyFooClass` (inside reg '"' is removed)
3. postpone changed reg '"' to normal `p` behavior.

Comment: You should not be "overloading" the commonly used `p` command just for header generation (less common operation). It would probably be best to look for ways to either generate your headers or create a Vim command to aid you in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression mapping and an autocommand to accomplish this:

```
autocmd BufRead *.h nnoremap <expr> p v:register != '=' && getreg(v:register) =~ '\w\+\s\+\w\+::\w\+([^)]*)' ? ":pu=substitute(getreg(v:register), '\\(\\w\\+\\)\\s\\+\\w\\+::\\(\\w\\+([^)]*)\\).*', '\\1 \\2;', '')\<cr>\<cr>-" : 'p'
```

I will leave mapping all of Vim's other put/paste (`P`, `gp`, `gP`, `]p`, `[p`, ...) command as an exercise for the reader.

Personally I think this would be best as a Vim command e.g. `:PutHeader` or some alternative way to generate header files.